# Presto equivalent to StringTokenizerDelim (Vertica) / Explode(Python)

Tags: sql, presto

I am migrating a query from Vertica to Presto(0.246). The query contains a Vertica function StringTokenizerDelim, which basically explodes and array (market column) into rows.

This is the mockup of the table:

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | product |   market    |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 | Cabinet | AU,GB,FR    |
|  2 | Chair   | US,GB       |
|  3 | Desk    | BE,GB,FR,US |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

The output should be:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | product | market |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | Cabinet | AU     |
|  1 | Cabinet | GB     |
|  1 | Cabinet | FR     |
|  2 | Chair   | US     |
|  2 | Chair   | GB     |
|  3 | Desk    | BE     |
|  3 | Desk    | GB     |
|  3 | Desk    | FR     |
|  3 | Desk    | US     |
+----+---------+--------+
```

What is the equivalent to that function in Presto (if there is any? couldn't find it on the documentation)?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`split`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#split) with [`UNNEST`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html?#unnest) should do the trick:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (id, product,   market ) AS (
    values (1, 'Cabinet', 'AU,GB,FR'),
    (2, 'Chair', 'US,GB'),
    (3, 'Desk', 'BE,GB,FR,US')
) 

--query
SELECT id, product, m as market
FROM dataset
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (split(market, ',')) as t(m)
```

Output:

| id | product | market |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cabinet | AU |
| 1 | Cabinet | GB |
| 1 | Cabinet | FR |
| 2 | Chair | US |
| 2 | Chair | GB |
| 3 | Desk | BE |
| 3 | Desk | GB |
| 3 | Desk | FR |
| 3 | Desk | US |

Comment: Thanks mate,
As the mockup is a specific example, is there a way to put the WITH statement in a more of a programatic way? I am talking about the content of the Values()?

Comment: did you see my full comment?

Comment: @Michael.s as for the `WITH` - TBH not following you. In my answer it is used only to provide example data so you don't need it in your actual query (you should just use corresponding table in `FROM` instead of `dataset`). But you can use `WITH` to [simplify nested queries](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#with-clause).

Comment: @Michael.s yes. See my second comment.